# How to send data to web page as soon as data is added to the database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to make feature like on the first page of foursquare.com (feed auto scroll). And I found how to make it [here](http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/scrolling-list) . But I have another problem. I want to add new feed as soon as some data is added to database (like foursquare) but I don't have idea how to make it. I suppose that I need somehow send data from database to page or read from database every second. What would be the best way to realize this?

Ok I decided to make call to database with following code on every 5 seconds. I just need some confirmation that this is the valid and secure way to do this please?

```
function init() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.post('http://localhost:2993/home/test', function (data) {
                smoothAdd('scroller', data);
            });
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: Assuming you are using an SQL Server database, take a look at SqlCacheDependency. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

Comment: How "live" does the data need to be? For example, is a 5 second delay within your requirement?

Comment: There should not be delay. I need to keep eye on table from database. When new row is added that must be immediately displayed in a feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize interval and try to reach data on the server:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.post('foursquare.com/newfeeds', function (data) {
        $('#scroller').prepend('<li>' + data + '</li>');
    });
}, 5000);
```

also 1 second is too often. Use 5 or even 10 seconds

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at SignalR: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR which makes long polling easy.

Answer (score 0):

We used to do this in our online trading system, where we had a grid view populated with stock prices, and needed to keep this grid up to date. What we did is that every two seconds we send an AJAX request to the server, the server will return the new data in the form of a JSON string, then back on the client side, we used pure javascript to process the returned data and add them to the grid or update existing records.

Answer (score 0):

If you observer foursquare feeds, it just rotates the news by fetching 50 or 100 rows in one shot. It periodically checks for new news and not often.

You should check out Sqlcachedependency which will be the best option for this. If you have 1000 users on your site and if you fetch data for 5 seconds each for OL users, calculate how many times it will hit your db to display latest news.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about SQL Server (stop reading if you're not), you would likely be well served by SQL Server [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) to monitor for these changes, then something like SignalR for notify the clients.

I wrote a helper library called [SQL Watcher](http://lab.arc90.com/2009/02/05/sqlwatcher-ad-hoc-database-change-monitoring/) a couple years back that might be helpful for the first half of this.